# pip not running with Python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, pip, ubuntu-12.04

I have installed Python 3.5 and Pip but When I am type pip or pip3 in console, i get this error

> The folder you are executing pip from can no longer be found.

If I run pwd, I get

> /home/zahid

Pip was installed using

```
sudo python /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/easy_install.py pip
```

and output that I got was

```
[sudo] password for zahid: 
Searching for pip
Best match: pip 8.1.1
Adding pip 8.1.1 to easy-install.pth file
Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip3.5 script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip3 script to /usr/local/bin

Using /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Processing dependencies for pip
Finished processing dependencies for pip
```

Can anyone tell me what is going on  here

which python3 returns

> /usr/bin/python3

which pip returns

> /usr/local/bin/pip

which pip3 returns

```
/usr/local/bin/pip3
```

echo $PYTHONPATH returns

```
nothing blank
```

Regards

Comment: First check: give the output of `which python3`, `which pip`, `which pip3`, `echo $PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl I have updated PYTHONPATH to **/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/:/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/** but the error is still the same.

Comment: In you current directory, does `ls` work?

Comment: Yes ls does, is there a way for me to uninstall all the python and install a fresh copy?

Comment: Setting PYTHONPATH will likely cause more confusion. There are several possible issues with your setup: 1. python 2/3 clash and 2. system vs /usr/local clash. If possible start by uninstalling any instance of python3 from the ubuntu install. make sure that python3 points to /usr/local/bin/python3 and see if that works. Remove any `~/.local/lib` package and re-install pip.

Comment: (disclaimer: I wrote the package I recommend here) the package `whych` is made to diagnose this type of issue. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/whych as your pip is in bad state, you could simply download the source and use setup.py to install it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142345/discussion-between-zahid-and-pierre-de-buyl).

Answer (score 8):

Please close this terminal and open a new terminal. You may have deleted some files inadvertently. As a result the terminal is unable to locate some links or environment variables. I faced the same issue. In a new terminal everything went fine.

Answer (score 6):

I had this error on my Mac and restarting fixed this problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Does `sudo pip` work?

If so, check to make sure your profile isn't messed up. Check your path variable using the echo command with something like  `echo $PATH`

You need to make sure `/usr/local/bin` is present in your user profile.

If not, did you install pip into 3.5 and are you accidentally running some other version of python like python 2?

Comment: yes $PATH has /usr/local/bin and yes I am trying to install pip with python 3.5

Comment: sudo pip does not work and returns **sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
The folder you are executing pip from can no longer be found.**

Answer (score -1):

Create a symbolic link using

```sh
ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/bin/pip
```

test it by running

```sh
pip -V
```